# How to export from Blender to unity3d

Tags: unity, blender, export

I have a simple object created from PLANE, in BLENDER version 2.72, where I edged the edges to the height. How do I correctly export the model to Unity3d I have version 4.7 to make all walls visible? Figure 2. Sorry for the wrong English. Thanks for your advice

Picture 1 in Blender 
[image: Picture 1 in Blender]

object export .obj in unity 
[image: object export .obj in unity]

Answer (score 1):

Unity automatically converts blender to unity meshes/objects.

You're probably having issue with normals here.

In edit mode select all faces and hit ctrl+n then pick which direction you want the face to be.

Before:

[image: before]

After selecting all and hitting ctrl+n

[image: inside]

After togeling inside

[image: after]

Notice how the faces are lighter? It's a quick indication of which face the normal is pointing at.

The normals can be shown by enabling one of the options for normals in the right properties of the 3D view ( if it isn't showing up, just hit n )

> I have version 4.7

That's ancient tho, any reason you're not using unity 2017?

Comment: Normally it does not work. Unity 2017 I do not use because I have windows XP

Comment: What does not work?